# Having problem with look and feel (JTattoo) when open it from another frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

I want to implement Acryl Look and Feel. It does work if I open it as the main() class
However, When i open it from another Frame ( such as helloword Frame ), the JTatoo doesn't work as I expected . And my Frame(The one with JTatoo), it return to the default L&F.
And It also affect my code on my Frame like JFreeChart doesn't work as it should be 
 `

This is my helloword frame code:

```
int a=0;
public ManHinhChao() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
    setTitle("Màn hình chào");
    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    t1.start();
}
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        a++;
        try {
            ProBar.setMinimum(0);
            ProBar.setMaximum(100);
            ProBar.setValue(a);
            if (a == 10) {
                this.setVisible(false);
                new Quanly().setVisible(true);
            }
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`
    [image: This is when I open it as a main]
[image: This is when I open it from helloword frame]

Comment: Don't try to mix look-and-feels. Choose one and use it for all GUI elements.

Comment: It is working now
Thanks a lot